# why ob_start() must come ahead of session_start() to work in PHP?

Tags: php, session, ob-start

I don't think it's reasonable.

Why is it actually such a rule?

Comment: frankly speaking: i've haven't heard of such rule!

Answer (score 15):

In the "*normal case*", I don't think `ob_start` has to be called before `session_start` -- nor the other way arround.

Quoting the [manual page of `session_start`](http://www.php.net/session_start), though :

> session_start() will register internal
>   output handler for URL rewriting when
>   trans-sid is enabled. If a user uses
>   ob_gzhandler or like with ob_start(),
>   the order of output handler is
>   important for proper output. For
>   example, user must register
>   ob_gzhandler before session start.

But this is some kind of a special case : the thing is, here, that the order of output handlers is important : if you want one handler to modify things the other did, they have to be executed in the "right" order.

Generally, if you don't use that kind of handlers *(Apache and [`mod_deflate`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_deflate.html) do a great job when it comes to compressing output, for instance)*, the only thing that matters is that headers must not be sent before you call `session_start` *(because, depending on your configuration, `session_start` sends cookies, which are passed as HTTP headers)*.

And headers are sent as soon as any piece of data has to be sent -- ie, as soon as there is any output, even one whitespace outside of `<?php ?>` tags :

> Note: If you are using cookie-based
>   sessions, you must call
>   session_start() before anything is
>   outputted to the browser.

`ob_start` indicates that PHP has to buffer data :

> This function will turn output
>   buffering on. While output buffering
>   is active no output is sent from the
>   script (other than headers), instead
>   the output is stored in an internal
>   buffer.

This way, output is not sent before you actually say, yourself, "*send the data*". This means headers are not send immediatly -- which means `session_start` can be called later, even if there should have been output, if `ob_start` had not been used.

*Hope this makes things a bit more clear...*

Answer (score 6):

If by default your `output_buffering` is `Off` and you have been unfortunate enough to send a single byte of data back to the client then your `HTTP` headers have already been sent. Which effectively prevents `session_start()` from passing the cookie header back to the client. By calling `ob_start()` you enable buffering and therefore delay sending http headers.

Answer (score 0):

`session_start` might want to modify the HTTP header if certain configuration options are set. One for example is [*session.use_cookies*](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-cookies) that requires to set/modify the *Set-Cookie* header field.

Modifying the HTTP header requires that there isn’t any output that’s already sent to the client as the [HTTP header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4)  is sent right before the first output is sent.

So you either ensure that there is absolutely no output before the call of `session_start`. Or you use the [output buffering control](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) to buffer the output so that the HTTP header can be modified even if there already is output.

Answer (score 0):

`session_start()` will register internal output handler for URL rewriting when `trans-sid` is enabled. If a user uses `ob_gzhandler` or like with `ob_start()`, the order of output handler is important for proper output.

For example, the user must register `ob_gzhandler` before session start.

But this is some kind of a special case. The thing is, here, that the order of output handlers is important. If you want one handler to modify things the other did, they have to be executed in the "right" order.

Generally, if you don't use that kind of handlers (Apache and `mod_deflate` do a great job when it comes to compressing output, for instance), the only thing that matters is that headers must not be sent before you call `session_start` (because, depending on your configuration, `session_start` sends cookies, which are passed as HTTP headers).

And headers are sent as soon as any piece of data has to be sent -- ie, as soon as there is any output, even one whitespace outside of `<?php ?>` tags :

**Note:** If you are using cookie-based sessions, you must call `session_start()` before anything is outputted to the browser.

`ob_start` indicates that PHP has to buffer data :

This function will turn output buffering on. While output buffering is active no output is sent from the script (other than headers), instead the output is stored in an internal buffer.

This way, output is not sent before you actually say, yourself, "send the data". This means headers are not send immediatly -- which means session_start can be called later, even if there should have been output, if `ob_start` had not been used.

Answer (score 0):

session_start(); should be called before any headers are sent out. ob_start() will suppress the output for a while and you can break this rule. Usually ob_start() on the top is a quick fix in case you are debugging something unknown; everything below works as expected (not just as written ;-)). I prefer to use ob_start() later to session_start().

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, ob_start() is used to start output buffering. Output buffering captures all output sent to the browser and stores it in a buffer, allowing you to manipulate it before sending it to the browser.

When using sessions in PHP, it is important to call ob_start() before starting the session, as sessions rely on cookies, which are sent to the browser as part of the HTTP headers. If any output has already been sent to the browser before the session is started, the headers will have already been sent and it will not be possible to set the session cookies.

By calling ob_start() before starting the session, any output that is generated before the session is started will be captured by the buffer and will not be sent to the browser. This allows the session cookies to be set correctly, even if some output has already been generated.

**In summary, ob_start() is necessary for session in PHP because it ensures that headers can be sent correctly even if there is output generated before the session is started.**