# Why ob_start() solves the header() error?

Tags: php

I have a script that has a call to `header();` and its working fine for a couple of days since I first started running the script.

then after a couple of days, it started to have an error saying it cannot modify header information.

Then I put `ob_start();` and `ob_end_flush();` upon googling the error and it works!

The error has gone but my question is that why it works without `ob_start();` and `ob_end_flush();` for a couple of days before?

I want to know the explanation behind this behavior.

btw, I call `header()` this way:

```
if(condition is true){
header('Location: anotherpage.php');
}
```

and I have a `session_start();` at the beginning.

Comment: You need to paste your code here.

Comment: check this : http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Comment: Did it start failing because you tried to output something before the `header();`?

Comment: read about `ob_` functions. but in few words: this functions stores ewrything what you output by your script, so when u set headers, you are sure that nothing was outputted before.

Comment: @TinkuRana I read it and its hard to comprehend why Im having that stranged behavior.

Comment: have u added session into action after couple of days because me too faced similar strange problem after adding session into action otherwise it was worked fine.

Comment: php header function gives error if any output is there before header function. ob_start function stop any output from script

Comment: @DipeshParmar yes I have a `session_start();` at the beginning.

Comment: here is ur ans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450990/why-ob-start-must-come-ahead-of-session-start-to-work-in-php

Comment: ob_start() doesn't actually solve the problem, it works round it.

To solve the problem, you need to identify what is being output before the headers and actually fix it

Answer (score 2):

Previously, you had no non-header output before the header line. Now, you have non-header output before the header line. That will only work if the output is buffered so the header can be actually output ahead of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can not output any data before a header!

ob_start() is a output buffer and will buffer all echoed data and print it after all headers etc.

PHP flushes the data when the script is finished automatically so there's no need of the "ob_end_flush()"

Answer (score 1):

You have some code outputting something before `header()` is called. It can be a `print`, `echo` or similiar statement, or even a white space before `<?php`.

The reason why `ob_start` causes the error to go away is because it causes any output to be buffered, therefore defered until the moment you call `ob_flush`.

This way it's guaranteed that the headers will come before content, even if you mess with the order of the commands in the code.