# php session_start()-phpDesigner

Tags: php, phpdesigner

I know this has been asked many times but my code works fine with no errors when it runs on the hosting company's server. I only get this error when I run it from phpDesigner:

```
PHP Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent in C:\Development\PHP_Projects\BrothersNetLogger\index.php on line 3 PHP Stack trace: PHP 1. {main}()
```

The index.php starts like this:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
?>
```

I have tried every fix suggested in the forum with no luck. It would seem that the problem is specific to phpDesigner. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Put `session_start()` before `ob_start()`. Does that fix it?

Comment: If it works on the servers, but not in your IDE... I would say your IDE is broken, do you really want to continue using it?

Comment: i think your problem already solved by [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450990/why-ob-start-must-come-ahead-of-session-start-to-work-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

**ob_start** — Turn on output buffering

If by default your output_buffering is Off and you have been unfortunate enough to send a single byte of data back to the client then your HTTP headers have already been sent. Which effectively prevents session_start() from passing the cookie header back to the client. By calling ob_start() you enable buffering and therefore delay sending http headers.Maybe you get  PHP Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent..

## so you can try

```
<?php
    session_start();
    ob_start();

?>
```

instated of

```
?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();


?>
```

here is some useful [link](http://www.nairaland.com/1821749/im-getting-warning-session-start) for you